# How can I use /setblock in 1.12 to make a blue banner?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to be able to use `/setblock` to make a blue banner in Minecraft 1.12.

So far I have the following command in progress:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:standing_banner 4
```

But I've tried adding `4`, `Damage:4`, `Base:4`, etc to the end, but the banner is always black.

How do I make it blue?

I understand that in 1.13 and above, different banner backgrounds have different colours, for example, `blue_banner`. But in 1.12 this functionality has not been added yet. How can I achieve the same in 1.12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answer is for 1.12 and older versions.*

---

Your attempt using `Base:4` is the closest to the correct way. However, this is attempting to set a data value. This only sets the direction of the standing banner, not the background colour.

You need to move the `Base:4` to the area where NBT tags are stored, in the `{}`s after the data value and old block handling.

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:standing_banner 0 replace {Base:0}
```

Here's a refresher of the possible values for the banner, for yours and the viewers' conveniences.

- 0: Black
- 1: Red
- 2: Green
- 3: Brown
- 4: Blue
- 5: Purple
- 6: Cyan
- 7: Light Gray
- 8: Gray
- 9: Pink
- 10: Lime
- 11: Yellow
- 12: Light Blue
- 13: Magenta
- 14: Orange
- 15: White

Comment: Thats literally exactly what I tried, i guess with the exception of replace. I should be able to setblock without replacing. Anyways it works now so thanks.